# Get category list & taxonomy list from different post type using post id?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

Is it possible to display list of category & list of taxonomy from different post_type using post id?

I tried get_the_term_list but it just output the currect post's taxonomy/category. What i want is to specify a post id (from different post_type, and it will display the taxonomy/category based on that given id from that different post_type).

Is it possible? Any help or Sample codes would be much appreciated.

Comment: please post the full relevant code of the template. did you pass the `$id` parameter into the function call? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Comment: Sorry for confusing question. I have updated it. I wanted to display list of taxonomy from different post_type & by using it's postid. Is it possible?

Comment: Nevermind, i get it now. XD Thanks for the reference.